# How to implement token auto refreshing with react redux axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

This situation occurs when user types a lot of information to some field or form, then token expires. In that case user loses all of the information. Therefore we should implement auto token refreshing functionality

Here is the middleware config

```
const middlewareConfig = {
  interceptors: {
    request: [
      ({ getState, dispatch }, config) => {
        return config;
      },
    ],
    response: [
      {
        error: ({ getState, dispatch, getSourceAction }, error) => {
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            dispatch(actions.setAuthErrorStatus());
          }
          if (error.response.headers.hasOwnProperty('sso-authenticate')) {
            redirectToLocationUrl(error.response.headers["sso-authenticate"])
          } else if (error.response.config.method === 'get') {
            if (url_config.DEFAULT_CLIENT === 'local_proxy') {
              cancelEventNotification(error);
            }
          }
          return Promise.reject(error);
        },
        success: ({ dispatch }, response) => {
          redirectToLocationUrl(response.headers.location);
          return response;
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  returnRejectedPromiseOnError: false,
};
```

This is a file where store creates

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { multiClientMiddleware } from 'redux-axios-middleware';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { clients } from './middlewares/axiosMiddleware/clients';
import config from './middlewares/axiosMiddleware/config';
import reducers from './reducers';

interface IRootChildren {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

const middlewares = [reduxThunk, multiClientMiddleware(clients, config)];
const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));

export default ({ children }: IRootChildren) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={ store }>
      { children }
    </Provider>
  );
};
```